# unable to pass array from controller to view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i am new to laravel and i have been following the documentation and several videos but for hours now i have been trying to pass an array from the controller to a view but i keep getting this error in the view:

```
Undefined variable: quiz
```

This is the controller code:

```
public function SetQuestions($id)
{
    $query = Quiz::find($id);

    $quiz = array(
        'id' => $query->id,
        'noQuestions' => $query->no_questions,
        'totalQuizScore' => $query->total_quiz_score
    );
    return View::make('quiz.set-questions')->with($quiz);
}
```

This is the route:

```
Route::resource("/quiz/set-questions/{id}", 'QuizController@SetQuestions');
```

This is the code in the view:

```
 <?php var_dump($quiz); ?>
```

For now i'm just dumping the data to see if the value changes form null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views) the view method takes two arguments. The first is the name of the variable you want it to be accessible by in the view, the second is the actual data.

```
return View::make('quiz.set-questions')->with('quiz', $quiz);
```

There are also a few other options

```
return View::make('quiz.set-questions')->withQuiz($quiz);

return View::make('quiz.set-questions', array('quiz'=>$quiz));

return View::make('quiz.set-questions', compact($quiz));
```

All these have the same result

Comment: I tried this too and it didn't work, i tried accessing the value form the view with Session::get('quiz') but the value always came up as NULL.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Does `return View::make('quiz.set-questions')->with('quiz', 'test');` show NULL as well?

Comment: Nope with 'test' works but when i try passing the array it comes up as NULL.

Comment: And what if you use a "sample" array? like `$quiz = array('id' => 1, 'totalQuizScore' => 100);`

Comment: However i just tried "return View::make('quiz.set-questions')->withQuiz($quiz);" and that worked fine thank you, is there any reason why that worked and the others did not? I would like to know for future reference. :)

Comment: Are you really really sure it didn't work with `with('quiz', $quiz)`? `withQuiz` actually does nothing else than call `with` internally (while transforming the second part of the method name into the first argument of `with`)

Comment: This is totally weird and I have no idea why. Let me know if you find out

Answer (score 1):

Use [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) and then just call `$quiz` in your view.

```
public function SetQuestions($id)
{
    $query = Quiz::find($id);

    $quiz = array(
        'id' => $query->id,
        'noQuestions' => $query->no_questions,
        'totalQuizScore' => $query->total_quiz_score
    );
    return View::make('quiz.set-questions', compact('quiz'));
}
```

Comment: I tried this and i was still getting the same undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5 you have to do something like this.

```
Route::get('/', function(){

  $people = ['John','Joe','Jack']; 

  return view('welcome',compact('people'); 

});
```

If you pass `$people` you will get an error.