# Failed to pass result from controller to view in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple class called MyClass like so:

```
namespace App\MyDomain;

class MyClass{

    private $msg;

    public function __construct($msg){

        $this->msg = $msg;

    }

    public function saySomething(){

        return $this->msg;

    }
}
```

And I have a simple test view called testView.blade.php under Pages subfolder like so:

```
<h3>Test View page</h3>

<p>Content before</p>

<p>Contents from controller: 

    <ul>

        @foreach($results as $result)

            <li>{{$result}}</li>

        @endforeach

    </ul>

</p>

<p>Content after</p>
```

And below is what my Routes look like:

```
Route::get('/sandbox', 'PageController@getData');
```

And in my PageController, I have a method getData like so:

```
public function getData(){

     $results = new MyClass('aloha');

    // I can see the variable when dumping
    // dd($results); 

    // but this is not working. it only displays the test view but not the results variable
    return view('pages.testView',compact('results')); 

    }
```

So when I hit the 'sandbox' URI, I should hit the controller and get the result back to my view and then I should see the word 'aloha' but its just empty. I don't see the variable result in the view.

I've also tried the suggestion on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071828/unable-to-pass-array-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel) but I dont think it applies to my version or I just don't know how to make it work

Is there something I missed? thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you tried to output `$results` in `getData()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I forgot to call the method of my MyClass that's why its not visible on the view.

```
public function getData(){

    $obj = new MyClass('aloha');

    $result = $obj->saySomething();

    return view('pages.testView',compact('result'));
}
```

Now its working ;-)

```
<h3>Test View page</h3>

<p>Content before</p>

<p>Contents from controller: 

            {{ $result }}

</p>

<p>Content after</p>
```

thanks guys for your comments. it gave me the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are looping over a single Object. In your view, remove the `foreach` loop and simply do.

```
<ul>
    <li>{{ $result->saySomething() }}</li>
<ul>
```

Your `$results` variable contains 1 instance of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

you try to loop over the object. `{{ var_dump($results) }}` to see the object. If you want to see the message. `{{ $results->saySomething() }}`